# OnDelete-Cascade is not being "fired"

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent, mariadb

I'm stuck on this point:

I got some migrations like this:

```
<?php

Schema::create('product_categories', function ( $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->timestamps();
});


Schema::create('products', function ( $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('category_id')->nullable();
    $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('product_categories')->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

This results in:

```
CREATE TABLE `product` (
 `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `category_id` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `product_category_id_foreign` (`category_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `product_category_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`category_id`) REFERENCES `product_categories` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

But if I remove the `product` row, the `category`-row remains untouched.

Any idea what kind of mistake I did?

Comment: what do you want to achieve exactly? you are having 3 tables products, categories, and pivot table product categories?

Comment: It works the other way around. If you delete a category, all products with that category will also be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So right now it will delete your product when deleting the product_category reference only, as that is how you have referenced it.

I assume there is your category table that you haven't linked? If you want the category to be deleted on a product being deleted, you'd have to reference the product in your category table with `->onDelete('cascade')` on the end. Although I'm not sure this is desirable, but I think that is what you are trying to do?